# R: rowwise nth element ordered_by row values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this input:

`t <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,8,4), y=c(2,3,4,5), k=c(3,4,5,1))`

And want to have the rowwise nth-lowest element of the dataframe ordered by the rowwise values, so that the output is something like this (example for nth_element = 2):

```
[1] 2 3 5 4
```

I tried a function like this:

```
apply(t, 1, nth, n=1, order_by = .)
```

But this does not work. Two questions:

- What should I type in the order_by gument to make this function work?
- Which is the best way to summarise rows with an own summary function if I don't want to mention the column names in the rowwise summary function?

Sidenote:

- I don't want to mention the column names specifically, I want the function to use all rows in the dataset.
- I tried the rownth function from the Rfast package but it only provides one result. Does anybody know what I do wrong?

Comment: It's not clear to me what is you expected output. I can't see the sequence `2 3 5 4` anywere in the dataframe, more over `2 3 4` is both the second row and the second column. What is that you are trying to do?

Comment: I want the nth lowest element per row. For a row of 1, 3, 2, the 2-nd lowest element would be 2

Comment: For Rfast package you should choose the nth value for each column/row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `apply` and `sort` to do this.

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,8,4), y=c(2,3,4,5), k=c(3,4,5,1))

nth_lowest <- 2
apply(d, 1, FUN = function(x) sort(x)[nth_lowest])
# [1] 2 3 5 4
```

Note that I am calling the data `d` instead of `t`. `t` is already a reserved name in `R` (matrix transpose function).

Answer (score 1):

Not as elegant as @bouncyball's answer, but using `dplyr` (and `tidyr`), one possibility is to do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

t %>% mutate(Row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Row, names_to = "Col", values_to = "Val") %>%
  group_by(Row) %>% 
  arrange(Val) %>% 
  slice(2) %>% 
  select(Val)

Adding missing grouping variables: `Row`
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   Row [4]
    Row   Val
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     2     3
3     3     5
4     4     4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Rfast you could reduce run time for big matrices and for matrices only.

```
d <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,8,4), y=c(2,3,4,5), k=c(3,4,5,1))
d<- Rfast::data.frame.to_matrix(d)

nth_lowests <- rep(2,ncol(d))
Rfast::rownth(d,nth_lowests)
# [1] 2 3 5 4
```

You could also use the parallel version of Rfast::rownth